# 32 internal error "A device attached to the system is not functioning" 0x1F occurred while setting the console window title

Tags: powershell, tfs-2015, sqlcmd, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have multiple databases and have multiple sql scripts (250+). I am executing all the sql scripts on each of these databases. I am executing these scripts using SQLCMD.exe through PowerShell.

It is working fine when I am executing through 'Windows PowerShell ISE'. But following error is coming when I am executing this from TFS 2015 Release Definition:

**The Win32 internal error "A device attached to the system is not functioning" 0x1F occurred while setting the console window title. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.**

**One Observation:**

I have tried with reducing the SQL scripts or database with changing the order of database; but every time the procedure get fails after executing **3333 SQL scripts**. So the problem might be of any Buffer size.

The SQLCMD execution line, I am using is as below:

```
& $SQLCMDFilePath -S $SQLServerName -d $DatabaseName -U $SQLServerUsername -P $SQLServerPassword -i $ScriptFullPath -b -l 60 -I -r -m 1 -o $fileName
```

Anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a solution that worked for me:
*Just ran into this problem and solved it by selecting a true type font for Windows command prompt*
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/9c2b54a0-34dd-413e-ae32-ad2a00c3b12b/utf8-encoding-not-working?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32664971)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The solution is very simple. No need for the link.